# how to make a file clickable in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code fragment :

```
fs.readdir(__dirname, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    
    files.forEach(function (filename) {
        fname = filename;
        console.log("fname = " + fname );
        res.write('<a href= \"' + fname + '\">'  + fname + '<br>');
        res.write("\n\n");
      });
        res.end();
    });
    });
```

I want to make the fname clickable.

I did it by doing like above, but it is simply displaying the entire text as it is. I want to open that particular file by just clicking on it. Please help me out on this!

---

#### note:

fname is a global variable, so there is no problem with this.

Comment: You haven't closed the `a` tag --> `res.write('<a href="' + fname + '">'  + fname + '</a><br>');`

Answer (score 1):

Close your `a`-tag should fix your problem.

You also have one `});` too many.

---

Corrected code :

```
fs.readdir(__dirname, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    files.forEach(function (filename) {
        fname = filename;
        console.log("fname = " + fname );
        res.write('<a href= \"' + fname + '\">'  + fname + '</a><br>');
        res.write("\n\n");
    });
    res.end();
});
```